# What is the SASS equivalent of additive mixin definitions in LESS?

Tags: sass

Is there a way to have SASS emulate the way LESS concatenates repeated mixin definitions (redefining a mixin in LESS doesn't overwrite the original).

For instance, would it be possible to push a block of CSS rules into a buffer, and then flush them all at once?

#### Example:

With LESS I'd do this:

```
// _menu.less
#_base ()    { .menu{ /*styles*/ }  }
#_mobile ()  { .menu{ /*styles*/ }  }
#_desktop () { .menu{ /*styles*/ }  }
```

...

```
// _widget.less
#_base ()    { .widget{ /*styles*/ }  }
#_mobile ()  { .widget{ /*styles*/ }  }
#_desktop () { .widget{ /*styles*/ }  }
```

...

and then:

```
// styles.less
@import "_menu.less";
@import "_widget.less";

@media screen { #_base(); }
@media screen and (max-width:700px) { #_mobile(); }
@media screen and (min-width:701px) { #_desktop(); }
```

...

```
// styles-oldie.less
@import "_menu.less";
@import "_widget.less";

@media screen {
    #_base();
    #_desktop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to replicate what you want to achieve by building on to existing mixins. If you define a mixin two times, the second will overwrite the first. [See example](http://sassmeister.com/gist/22a56387ab645b2eb0cb)

AFAIK the common practice in Sass is to use media query mixins inside the selector to keep the code clean and readable. [Breakpoint](http://breakpoint-sass.com/) is a popular library that adds a lot of nice functionality for doing this.

An example of the code would be.

```
@import "breakpoint";

$medium: 600px;
$large: 1000px;

$breakpoint-no-queries: false;          // Set to true to ignore media query output
$breakpoint-no-query-fallbacks: true;   // Set to true to output no-query fallbacks
$breakpoint-to-ems: true;               // Change px to ems in media-queries

.menu {
  content: "base";

  // Mobile styles
  @include breakpoint(min-width $medium - 1) {
    content: "mobile";
  }

  // Tablet styles
  @include breakpoint($medium $large) {
    content: "tablet";
  }

  // Desktop styles with no-query fallback
  @include breakpoint($large, $no-query: true) {
    content: "large";
  }

}
```

This could output (depending on your settings)

```
.menu {
  content: "base";
  content: "large";
}
@media (min-width: 37.4375em) {
  .menu {
    content: "mobile";
  }
}
@media (min-width: 37.5em) and (max-width: 62.5em) {
  .menu {
    content: "tablet";
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62.5em) {
  .menu {
    content: "large";
  }
}
```

[You can play around with the settings here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/dd9bb3db899644487092)

I often have a stylesheet for modern browsers that support media queries set up like this:

```
// main.scss
$breakpoint-no-queries: false;
$breakpoint-no-query-fallbacks: false;

@import "imports";
```

And another stylesheet for older browsers that don't support media queries

```
// no-mq.scss
$breakpoint-no-queries: true;
$breakpoint-no-query-fallbacks: true;

@import "imports";
```